# Link tag not triggering onSubmit when clicking on the form's submit button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, onsubmit

For some reason when I wrap my Link tag around my form's submit button it doesn't trigger the onSubmit() function. What am I doing wrong?

```
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
  <form className="gift-search" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="giftSearch"
          placeholder="Search for any gifts"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    <Link to={{ pathname: `/category/${giftSearchState}` }}>
          <button type="submit" className="search-btn">
            Search
          </button>
        </Link>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would navigate programmatically using `useNavigate()` :

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  navigate(`/category/${giftSearchState}`);
}

...

<form className="gift-search" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="giftSearch"
      placeholder="Search for any gifts"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" className="search-btn">
    Search
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

Internally, the **react-router-dom** `Link` component will render an html link `<a>` with the children (in this case your button).

You can see the `Link` source code [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/62903564b85b0f7001b0be81b7a6b0c20d3fea9b/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L280).

But the problem is not that, [I created a sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cherry-fb6mw1?file=/src/App.tsx) using the button inside a `<a>` and inside a `<Link>`, and you can check for yourself that when you have a button inside a `<a/>`, if the button has the type=submit, then the form onSubmit will be called.

The problem is following:
The `Link` component has its own onClick function internally and it calls the `preventDefault` to allow only the back button click, you can see at [this line](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/62903564b85b0f7001b0be81b7a6b0c20d3fea9b/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L407)

So, what is happening is:

Your button is clicked, and the event is captured and not prevented, then the Link captures the event and call the preventDefault so it will never reach your `onSubmit` form function.

In the [codesand](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cherry-fb6mw1?file=/src/App.tsx), I let a console.log in the button onClick so you can see that the `event.button` is equal to `0`

The react-router-dom source code is really interesting, I recommend you to take a look :)